# How Can I Remove Epiphany Without Removing Gnome?

Tags: gnome, uninstall, dependencies, epiphany

I have Gnome Shell installed, and I want to remove the Epiphany browser.  But when I click uninstall in the software center its says that `Gnome-core` is a dependency of Epiphany, so it will be uninstalled too.

Is there anyway I can remove Epiphany without removing Gnome?

On running `sudo apt-get -s remove epiphany` as a commenter suggests, returns as not installed.   Its still in my program list though.

I found out, the package that is installed is `epiphany-browser`.  On running `sudo apt-get -s remove epiphany-browser`  it still wants to remove `gnome-core`.

Comment: Does it says `gnome` or `gnome-shell`, because `gnome` is a metapackage which can be uninstalled, and if you look at the dependencies in synaptic, it doesn't mention either `gnome` or `gnome-shell`.

Comment: Edited question.

Comment: Hmm how did you Installed Epiphany?

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get -s remove epiphany` in a terminal window. The `-s` option makes sure that nothing is removed, but you'll get the list of packages to review. Add it to the question if still unsure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gnome-core is just a metapackage.  You can remove it without much ill effect.

Its only provided files are a changelog and a copyright file.  It won't "hold" dependencies installed, you run a minor risk there, but nothing major.

[Reference](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/amd64/gnome-core/filelist)

Comment: I uninstalled it and haven't had any ill effects.

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove the `epiphany-browser` package. And if you installed any extra packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove epiphany-browser epiphany-browser-data epiphany-browser-data epiphany-extensions
```

Comment: It still says it will remove `gnome-core`